In the same docker-compose, how does the Nextjs server component request backend data?
As the title says, my front-end Nextjs project, back-end Django and Nginx are all configured in the same docker-compose.yml. The question now is how to request back-end data in the front-end server component. I have tried various URLs with "/api/v1/" as the core, but none of them work.
I really can't understand it, it should be a simple problem but I can't solve it after trying for a long time.
docker-compose configuration:
version: '3'
services:

  client:
    build:
      context: ./journey-journal-frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL=http://server:8000
    volumes:
      - app-volume:/app/.next
    user: "nextjs"
    depends_on:
      - server

  server:
    build:
      context: ./journey-journal-manage/admin_panel
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
    ports:
      - 8000:8000

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
    depends_on:
      - client
      - server

volumes:
  app-volume:
  static_volume:

nginx configuration：
  server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://client:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://server:8000;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For;                                   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /admin {
            proxy_pass http://server:8000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /static/ {
            alias /usr/src/app/staticfiles/;
        }
    }

Front-end configuration:
  const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: `/api/v1/`, // 设置 baseURL
  timeout: 10000, // 请求超时时间
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

I hope someone with more experience can tell me how to solve this problem, I would be very grateful for this

The general container setup looks right to me (compare "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend).  What is the exact error you're getting in the browser code?  If you look at the logs of the backend container, is it receiving a request, and does the HTTP path match what's in the application's routes?

The trouble is here. The front-end server component cannot request the back-end data in the docker container because the back-end network cannot be determined. They are in the same docker-compose. If localhost is used, the request to the client container itself will be rejected. I am still looking for a solution. This is a tricky problem! !

I know what the problem is, my bad, it's my weak basic knowledge！！！！
Thank you very much for your help！

I know the reason for this problem, because the request data is made in the server component of the Nextjs front-end project, which pulls data during the image compilation phase. At this time, the server in docker-compose has not been started, so of course no data can be obtained. Only after all services are built and started can other services be accessed.
Several solutions

Use environment variables or configuration files: Provide static
data or API URLs through environment variables or configuration
files during the build phase so that Next.js's SSG (static site
generation) can use this data at build time. If the data is dynamic,
you can fetch the data through client requests or using Next.js's
getServerSideProps while the application is running.

Prerender pages: If your application uses SSG, you can prerender
pages during the build phase. This means that you can generate
static pages from an already running backend service or use mock
data at build time. In this way, your front-end application does not
directly depend on the real-time availability of the backend service
at build time.

Use external data sources: If real-time data is required during the
build phase, consider storing the data in an external service (such
as a cloud database or API service) so that the data can be accessed
even during the build phase.

Delay data requests: With SSG, you can design your application to
request data when the client loads, rather than during the build
phase. This means that the static page will load first, and then the
backend service will be requested through JavaScript on the client
to fetch the data.

Manually trigger the build: If your data does not change frequently,
you can manually trigger the front-end build process when the
backend data is updated, which ensures that the data used during the
build is the latest.


